# How to make multi sub domains in laravel project?

Tags: laravel, authentication, dns, subdomain

Good Morning

> i have laravel project with has multi auth like admin, doctors,
>   hospitals ...etc but i have two questions

**First:** which is the best way to make multi auth?

> I made users table and made column named "type" with value (1: admin, 2:doctor, 3:hospital)

**Second:** How to make sub domain for each auth ?

> example -> admin.myproject.com, doctor.myproject.com, hospital.myproject.com

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think you refer to this https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing

Comment: [Tenancy](https://github.com/tenancy/multi-tenant) multi-tenant package can give you some ideas, check their code.

Comment: @ZeroOne
ok but how to make auth routes for every auth
when i hit admin.myproject.com i want to go to admin routes and when hit hospital.myproject.com i want to go to hospital routes depending on column type in users table

Comment: @Tpojka i think it for seperate projects but i have only one project with multi routes

Comment: Probably the best way is to use a Middleware to check this. This way you can just check if the current authenticated users is the same type as the url-prefix

Comment: @Christophvh Ok i'll give it a try